# How can I overlay the List plugin in RTE

Tags: aem

By default AEM add some class as below when I use the ordered list in the RTE.

```
 <ul style="list-style-position: inside;">
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li>Item 2</li>
 </ul>
```

I want to change to

```
 <ul class="some class">
 <li><font style='some font'>Item 1 </font> </li>
 <li><font style='some font'>Item 2 </font> </li>
 </ul>
```

So, for this I looked at the existing implementation here :

```
 /libs/clientlibs/granite/richtext/core/js/plugins/ListPlugin.js/
```

But I do not understand how AEM is applying default class and where I need to make change.

Comment: Have you tried to overlay the component and if yes is there an issue you are facing when adding your own class?

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand what I have to write in the overlayed JS, which pice of code is applying default style.

Comment: You can overlay the plugin. However, it seems to me that you are looking to style ‘<ul>’ and ‘<li>’ elements in RTE. cant you just use CSS with ‘ul’ and ‘ul li’ selectors directly? You don’t necessarily have to use a specific class. Unless you have a more advanced use-case?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have implemented this, I will post the code here later

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you're working on AEM 6.3.
Check on your AEM instance the following lib:

`/libs/clientlibs/granite/richtext/core/js/ListUtils.js`

check for the following code:

`com.addInlineStyles(listDom, {'list-style-position': 'inside'});`